# jQuery Accordion Collapse and Expand Issue (Parent & Child)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am working with jQuery Accordion menu, and found problems with parent and child navigation, and need urgent help, thanks

I expand fully of one parent menu and its child, and then click the heading in order to make it collapse. then i expand another heading, when i go back to click first heading, the child menu were not collapsing. is there a way to collapse all child heading of one parent when select another parent heading??

thanks :)

here is my code

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a>Link One - First Level</a></h3>
    <div class="accordionSecond">      
        <h6><a href="#">Second Level</a></h6>
        <div class="accordionLink"> 
        <a href="1.html">1.html</a>
        <a href="2.html">2.html</a>
        <a href="3.html">3.html</a>
        <a href="4.html">4.html</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3><a>Link Two - First Level</a></h3>
    <div class="accordionSecond">      
        <h6><a href="#">Second Level</a></h6>
        <div class="accordionLink"> 
        <a href="1.html">1.html</a>
        <a href="2.html">2.html</a>
        <a href="3.html">3.html</a>
        <a href="4.html">4.html</a>
        </div>
    </div>    

</div>
```

here is little script line

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion( {active: true,  collapsible: true, header: "h3", autoHeight: false, navigation: true, event: 'mouseup'}); 
    $(".accordionSecond").accordion( {active: true,  collapsible: true, header: "h6", autoHeight: false, navigation: true,event: 'mouseup'});
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to tap into the `changestart` event of the parent accordion. Here, you can collapse any child accordions:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    active: true,
    collapsible: true,
    header: "h3",
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    event: 'mouseup',
    changestart: function (event, ui) {
        ui.oldContent.accordion("activate", false);
    }
});
```

Using the `activate` method and passing it `false` tells accordion to collapse all sections.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/p2h8V/

Comment: can i ask you one more thing??? do you know how to disable the link once you on that page??

Comment: i think i find solution for that
 jQuery("a[href$='" + path + "']").removeAttr('href');

thanks for the help, Andrew.